# Why does LogMeIn not display all objects correctly?

Tags: java, display, logmein

I am using LogMeIn Free to connect to my Win XP Pro box from afar.  I am experiencing some oddities with it.

One video streaming site I use needs you to accept a java applet to view videos.   Only the outline of the dialog box appears.  I can not see any text or buttons within the dialog box.

Another program that seems to not want to let me view it is TED. www.ted.nu  I just see the outer edges of the dialog box but nothing inside.  I believe TED is also a java application.

Any ideas?  Does LogMeIn and java apps just not get along?  Are there settings I should be looking into?  I have the latest version of LogMeIn and Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post on the LogMeIn forums should resolve your issue.](http://community.logmein.com/logmein/board/message?board.id=16&thread.id=975)